# CSV parse + multidim arrays

Tags: php, regex, csv

```
59516,?O?L?h,27,80,67,13,1,84.6,40,4,1,32632,??,3,5,32640,AES,3,5,32210,\
???i?Z??,1,1.2,32263,?,1,1.2,3?T,1,1.2,32104,,1,1,40012,??,1,0.8
```

How would I explode/list this line and pull any field that contains a five-character number and the field immediately preceding it?

i.e. `$data['59516']['i']` would contain an array with

```
(32632=>1, 32640=>5, 32210=>5, 32263=>1.2,32104=>2, 40012=>1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure i fully understand your question, but it sounds like you want something like:

```
$items = str_getcsv($commaSeparatedList);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    if (strlen($items[$i]) == 5 && is_numeric($items[$i])) {
            var_dump($items[$i]); // current match
        if (isset($items[$i-1])) {
            var_dump($items[$i-1]); // item and one before it
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: should I also do is_int and some other stuff? how would i foreach each line?

Comment: you could check if is_numeric($items[$i])

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=,)(\d+),(\d{5})`

The `$matches[1]` has the value and the `$matches[2]` has your key.